# Как забиндить разные действия на зажатие и отжатие клавиши клавиатуры в tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, клавиатура

Я хочу сделать, чтобы в игре на нажатие "а" человек шёл влево, а когда отжимается "а", то остановился. Как мне это забиндить? Я гуглил, но мне ничего про отжатие не находило. Может подскажете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для обработки нажатия кнопки нужно привязываться к событию `<KeyPress>`, для отжатия - `<KeyRelease>`. Ниже пример движения кружка кнопками стрелок, с поддержкой движения по диагонали при одновременном зажатии, например, кнопок "вверх" и "влево".

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

circle = canvas.create_oval((150, 100, 170, 120), fill='yellow')
vx = 0
vy = 0


def on_key_press(event):
    global vx, vy
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        vx = -10
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        vx = 10
    elif event.keysym == 'Up':
        vy = -10
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        vy = 10


def on_key_release(event):
    global vx, vy
    if event.keysym in ('Left', 'Right'):
        vx = 0
    elif event.keysym in ('Up', 'Down'):
        vy = 0


root.bind('<KeyPress>', on_key_press)
root.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_key_release)


def game_loop():
    canvas.move(circle, vx, vy)
    root.after(50, game_loop)


game_loop()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Если целью стоит создать игру, то лучше перейти на PyGame. Там это можно осуществить.

```
while run:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= speed
```

Comment: Дело говорите. Но все же, если обойтись без перехода на PyGame?

Comment: К сожалению, я недостаточно знаю библиотеку tkinter...